should time range and evaluation interval match for grafana alerts?
I am trying to create my first alert in Grafana with AWS CloudWatch data source. There are two settings related to time that needs to be configured.
The query section has the "Time Range"

Also, the "Set evaluation behaviour" section has the evaluation interval to be configured.

Do we need to consider any rules while setting these values, to ensure that there will be no duplicate alerts. For instance, should "Time range" be equal or less than the evaluation interval. Please advise.
